# Find and replace a string if particular pattern is found in a line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

All I need to do is, search for `CCSID` in this file, wherever it finds `CCSID`, the `CHAR` in that line should be replaced with `NCHAR` and `VARCHAR` in that line should be replaced with `NVARCHAR2`.

I tried using sed and awk. But I couldn't find a perfect way to solve this issue.

```
 CREATE TABLE JCR.ICMSTSYSCONTROL (
            LIBRARYSERVERID  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            LANGUAGECODE  CHAR(3) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
            SYSSEGMENTID  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            SYSSEGMENTTHRESHLD  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            ACLBINDINGLEVEL  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            LIBRARYACLCODE  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            PUBACCESSENABLED  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            DFLTACLCHOICE  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            SMSCHOICE SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            TRACELEVEL SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            MAXUSERS INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            MAXUSERACTION  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            CURRENTUSERS  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            MAXLOGONRETRY  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            PASSWORDDURATION  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            SYSADMINEVENTFLAG  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            SYSTEMFLAG SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            DATABASETYPE  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            MAXTXDURATION  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            MAXRESULTSETSIZE  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            ALLOWTRUSTEDLOGON  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            DOCROUTINGUPDATE  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            DOCROUTINGFREQ  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            PLATFORM SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            SYSTIMEOUT SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            TIEUSERID CHAR(175) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
            TIEPASSWORD  CHAR(72) FOR BIT DATA DEFAULT NULL ,
            DATABASENAME  VARCHAR(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
            DBSCHEMANAME  VARCHAR(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
            TRACEFILENAME  VARCHAR(128) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
            ENCRYPTIONKEY  VARCHAR(128) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL ,
            KEEPTRACEOPEN  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            MULTIPLETRACEFILES  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            MAXTRACEFILESIZE  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            PATHICMROOT  VARCHAR(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
            PATHICMDLL VARCHAR(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
            SUSPENDSERVERTIME  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ,
            RMSTATUSINTERVAL  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            RMSTATUSTIMEOUT  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            TIEINTERVAL  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
            LSCURRENTVERSION  VARCHAR(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
            TRACEUSER CHAR(175) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
            DIMSGDIGESTALGO  SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
            DIENCRYPTIONALGO  SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
            CONSTRAINT JCR.ICMSTSYSCONTROLPK PRIMARY KEY( LIBRARYSERVERID ) )
            ;
```

The output should be like:

```
CREATE TABLE JCR.ICMSTSYSCONTROL (
                LIBRARYSERVERID  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                LANGUAGECODE  NCHAR(3) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
                SYSSEGMENTID  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                SYSSEGMENTTHRESHLD  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                ACLBINDINGLEVEL  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                LIBRARYACLCODE  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                PUBACCESSENABLED  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                DFLTACLCHOICE  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                SMSCHOICE SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                TRACELEVEL SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                MAXUSERS INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                MAXUSERACTION  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                CURRENTUSERS  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                MAXLOGONRETRY  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                PASSWORDDURATION  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                SYSADMINEVENTFLAG  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                SYSTEMFLAG SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                DATABASETYPE  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                MAXTXDURATION  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                MAXRESULTSETSIZE  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                ALLOWTRUSTEDLOGON  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                DOCROUTINGUPDATE  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                DOCROUTINGFREQ  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                PLATFORM SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                SYSTIMEOUT SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                TIEUSERID NCHAR(175) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
                TIEPASSWORD  CHAR(72) FOR BIT DATA DEFAULT NULL ,
                DATABASENAME  NVARCHAR2(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
                DBSCHEMANAME  NVARCHAR2(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
                TRACEFILENAME  NVARCHAR2(128) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
                ENCRYPTIONKEY  VARCHAR(128) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL ,
                KEEPTRACEOPEN  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                MULTIPLETRACEFILES  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                MAXTRACEFILESIZE  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
                PATHICMROOT  NVARCHAR2(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
                PATHICMDLL NVARCHAR2(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
                SUSPENDSERVERTIME  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ,
                RMSTATUSINTERVAL  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                RMSTATUSTIMEOUT  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                TIEINTERVAL  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
                LSCURRENTVERSION  NVARCHAR2(128) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
                TRACEUSER NCHAR(175) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
                DIMSGDIGESTALGO  SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
                DIENCRYPTIONALGO  SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
                CONSTRAINT JCR.ICMSTSYSCONTROLPK PRIMARY KEY( LIBRARYSERVERID ) )
                ;
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/CCSID/ { s/ CHAR(/ NCHAR(/; s/ VARCHAR(/ NVARCHAR2(/ }' file
```

- The first pattern searches for lines with containing `CCSID`. Then the part inside `{...}` takes effect.

  - `s/ CHAR(/ NCHAR(/;` replaces `CHAR(` (with a leading space) with  `NCHAR(`.
  - `s/ VARCHAR(/ NVARCHAR2(/` and replace `VARCHAR(` with `NVARCHAR2(`.

Comment: leading space is not a good idea since you can use `\b` or `\<` : `s/\bCHAR(/N&/;s/\bVARCHAR\b/N&2/`

Comment: Thats working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe '/CCSID/ and s/\bCHAR\b/N$&/ || s/\bVARCHAR\b/N$&2(/' file
```